# Media Query and Image Swapping

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport, imagesource

I want the image in my site to completely change when the browser is resized.
I've been using media-queries, but I can't seem to get it right. Any thoughts/tips?
The thing is I have tried the display trick with media query but its not working

I did this, but it's not working even when I am lowering the viewport. The image in the laptop viewport remains the same in the phone viewport.

```css
.blocks {
  height: 58%;
}

.mob {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  .mob {
    display: block;
  }
  .blocks {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 border:1px">

  <img class="blocks" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="laptop-mockup">
  <img class="mob" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000" alt="android-mockup">

</div>
```

The whole html and css code:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>News homepage</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@600;700;800&family=PT+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navigator">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""> <img src="C:\Users\91826\Desktop\news-homepage-main\css\images\logo.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation navbar-light">

          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon navi"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ms-auto navelement">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#footer">Home </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ms-auto navelement">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#pricing"> New </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ms-auto navelement">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#cta"> Popular </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ms-auto navelement">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer"> Trending </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ms-auto navelement">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#footer"> Categories </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-6 border:1px">

  <img class="blocks" src="C:\Users\91826\Desktop\news-homepage-main\css\images\image-web-3-desktop.jpg" alt="laptop-mockup">
  <img class="mob" src="C:\Users\91826\Desktop\news-homepage-main\css\images\image-web-3-mobile.jpg" alt="android-mockup">

</div>
      <div class="tag">
        <h1 class="tagline">The Bright<br />Future of<br />Web 3.0?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="read">
        <h1 class="readline">We dive into the next evolution of the web that claims to put the power of the platforms back into the hands of the people.
          But is it really fulfilling its promise?</h1>
      </div>
      <button class="button-50 readmore" type="button" name="button">READ MORE</button>
      <div class="col-lg-6 border:1px">
        <div class="new">
          <h1>New</h1>

          <h2>Hydrogen VS Electric Cars</h2>
          <h3>Will hydrogen-fueled cars ever catch up to EVs?</h3>
          <hr>

          <h2>The Downsides of AI Artistry</h2>
          <h3>What are the possible adverse effects of on-demand AI image generation?</h3>
          <hr>

          <h2>Is VC Funding Drying Up?</h2>
          <h3>Private funding by VC firms is down 50% YOY. We take a look at what that means.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 box">
            <img class="infoimg" src="C:\Users\91826\Desktop\news-homepage-main\css\images\image-retro-pcs.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 box">
            <div class="inf">
              <h1 class="infohead1 "> 01</h1>
              <h2 class="infohead2"> Reviving Retro PCs</h2>
              <h3 class="infohead3"> What happens when old PCs<br>are given modern upgrades?</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 box2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 box">
            <img class="infoimg" src="C:\Users\91826\Desktop\news-homepage-main\css\images\image-gaming-growth.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 box">
            <div class="inf1 inf">
              <h1 class="infohead1"> 02</h1>
              <h2 class="infohead2"> Top 10 laptops of 2022</h2>
              <h3 class="infohead3">Our best picks for various <br> needs and budgets.</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-lg-4 box2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 box">
            <img class="infoimg" src="C:\Users\91826\Desktop\news-homepage-main\css\images\image-top-laptops.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 box">
            <div class="inf">
              <h1 class="infohead1"> 03</h1>
              <h2 class="infohead2"> The Growth of Gaming</h2>
              <h3 class="infohead3">How the pandemic has sparked <br> fresh opportunities.</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




<hr class="hori">
    <div class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
      Coded by <a href="https://cyberoctane29.github.io/MySite/">Saswat Seth</a>.
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
       .navigator {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

body {
  padding: 0% 10% 2% 10%;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
}

:hover.nav-link {
  color: #6B728E;
}

.navigator {
  padding: 2% 5% 0% 0%;
}

.blocks {
  height: 58%;
}

.mob {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  .mob {
    display:block;
  }

  .blocks {
    display:none;
  }
}

.new {
  height: 85%;
  width: 23%;
  background: hsl(240, 100%, 5%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 140px;
  padding: 2%;
}

.navelement {
  padding-right: 6%;
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(35, 77%, 62%);
  font-family: 'noto sans';
  font-weight: 600;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-family: 'noto sans';
  font-weight: 700;
}

h3 {
  color: #6B728E;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 4% 0%;
  line-height: 25px;
}

hr {
  color: #fff;
  border-top: solid white;
}

.tag {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.tagline {
  font-family: 'noto sans';
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.read {
  padding: 2% 38%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 54px;
  right: -15px;
}

.readline {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #6B728E;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.button-50 {
  height: 49px;
  width: 200px;
  appearance: button;
  background-color: hsl(5, 85%, 63%);
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: #B73E3E 4px 4px 0 0, #000 4px 4px 0 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 20% 5% 10% 0%;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -45px;
  right: 45%;
}

.button-50:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-50:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-50:active {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125) 0 3px 5px inset;
  outline: 0;
}

.button-50:not([disabled]):active {
  box-shadow: #C9BBCF 2px 2px 0 0, #1d1716 2px 2px 0 1px;
  transform: translate(2px, 2px);
}

.readmore {
  margin: 10% 3% 5% 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.info {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
}

.infoimg {
  width: 315%;
  padding: 20%;
}

.infohead1 {
  color: #7D9D9C;
}

.infohead2 {
  color: #000;
}

.inf {
  padding: 30%;
  margin-left: 68px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hori {
  margin-top: 10%;
  color: #000;
  border-top: solid black;
}
```

Comment: a lot of smartphones are already wider than 350px, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Hi Saswat, check this on [MDN:  Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .mob {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:350px) {
    img{
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```